# Codechef giving wrong answer for a program that works locally

Tags: python, algorithm

**Problem statement:**

> According to Gregorian Calendar, it was Monday on the date 01/01/2001. If any year is input, 
>   Write a program to display what is the day on the 1st January of this year.
>
> Input
>
> The first line contains an integer T, total number of testcases. Then follow T lines, each line contains an integer year.
>
> Output
>
> Display the day on the 1st January of that year in lowercase letter.
>
> Constraints
>
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 1000
>
> 1900≤ A,B,C ≤2500
>
> Example
>
> Input
>
> 3
>
> 1994
>
> 1991
>
> 2014
>
> Output
>
> saturday
>
> tuesday
>
> wednesday

**Solution I submitted:**

```
import datetime
test = input("Enter no. of test cases ")
while (test):
    year = input("Enter the year ")
    day = datetime.date(int(year),1,1).strftime("%A")
    print (day.lower())
    test = int(test)-1
```

When I run locally everything works fine. The output is the same as given in the test cases. Why is it giving a wrong answer on Codechef?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to prompt for input, in fact it will give you wrong answer on almost all online judges. Following code gives correct answer.

```
import datetime
test = int(input())
while test:
    year = input()
    day = datetime.date(int(year),1,1).strftime("%A")
    print(day.lower())
    test -= 1
```